# CosmosDB Intermittent 503 errors

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am getting intermittent 503 errors on cosmosDB. They don't happen very frequently, but I'm wondering how I can resolve them. I have cosmosDB setup serverless, and I was wondering if in part that might be the root of the problem.

```
Response status code does not indicate success: ServiceUnavailable (503); Substatus: 20002; ActivityId: 3e5e8b5e-6672-401a-af01-3f046d5a6b81; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: ServiceUnavailable (503);
```

Answer (score 1):

[SubStatus 20002](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-service-unavailable#verify-the-substatus-code) is typically caused by client-side timeouts.

Next step is to troubleshoot why your SDK client instance is timing out. More details here, [Troubleshooting client side timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout?tabs=cpu-new#troubleshooting-steps).

Comment: To add to Mark's response, make sure to capture the [Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk#capture-diagnostics) which can help you investigate further